# Remove reduction from cosine similarity for prototypical network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, cosine-similarity

I've implemented a prototypical network in tensorflow that uses cosine similarity to compare the output of the model with the prototypes calculated before. This works fine but the problem is that it's very slow. The reason it's slow is because im having to do seperate cosine similarity calculations for each individual output with each individual prototype. This prevents it being potentially parallelized on a GPU. In tensorflow you can get the cosine similarity between a batch and a set of labels but it reduces the losses to a single value. This doesn't work for what I want because I need to find the smallest cosine similarity to each prototype. I've tried looking at the tensorflow website about this but I can't find a way to remove this reduction that it does. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out, you just need to set the cosine loss to be:

```
cosine_loss = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(reduction='none')
```